# how to show multiple selected options in mat select (check box)

Tags: angular, checkbox

i have a edit form in which i want to show selected options which are fetch from database.
following is html code

```
<mat-select placeholder="Select Year" [compareWith]="compareFn" formControlName="security_deposite_for" multiple>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let year of security_deposite_for_yr; let i = index;" [value]="year.val"
          (click)="tosslePerOne(i)">
          {{year.viewValue}}
        </mat-option>
        <mat-option #allSelected (click)="toggleAllSelection()" [value]="0">All</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
```

this is my function in which i get values from database

```
getSecurityDepositeDetailForEdit(bid_id){
this.abcSer.getgetSecurityDepositeDetail(bid_id).subscribe(
  res => {
    console.log('res in sec deposite',res);
    res.forEach(element => {
        this.checkedOptions.push({
          val: element.sec_deposite_year,
          viewValue: element.sec_deposite_year,
        });
    });
  },
  err => {
    console.log('err in sec details',err);
  }
)
```

}

following is compare function

```
compareFn(security_deposite_for_yr,checkedOptions) {
console.log('security_deposite_for_yr 1',security_deposite_for_yr);
console.log('checkedOptions',checkedOptions);
return security_deposite_for_yr && checkedOptions ? security_deposite_for_yr.val === checkedOptions.val : security_deposite_for_yr === checkedOptions;
}
```

in console **security_deposite_for_yr** has values, but **checkedOptions** does'nt show any value.

so how to show selected values in mat multi select

****Edit******

i have tried following code

```
getSecurityDepositeDetailForEdit(bid_id){
this.eauctionSer.getgetSecurityDepositeDetail(bid_id).subscribe(
  res => {
    console.log('res in sec deposite',res);
   this.tenderFrm.security_deposite_for.setValue([res.map(i => i.sec_deposite_year)]);
    // res.forEach(element => {
    //   this.tenFrm.security_deposite_for.setValue(element.sec_deposite_year);
    // });
    console.log('frm',this.tenderFrm.security_deposite_for.value);
  },
  err => {
    console.log('err in sec details',err);
  }
)}
```

but it shows 1st option selected in mat-select dropdown

Comment: Where are you patching value for security_deposite_for form control?

Comment: in another function following is code
`let selectedTenure = data[0].lic_period;
      for (let i = 1; i <= selectedTenure; i++) {
        this.security_deposite_for_yr.push({
          val: i,
          viewValue: i,
        });
      }`

Comment: A mat select multiple need an array, so in anytime you need has some like `yourform.get('security_deposite_for').setValue([bla,bla,bla]). I can not see when you do it

Comment: @Eliseo selectedTenure has count, same count i have used in for loop so it creates array